# Abnormal memory usage by a simple bash script

Tags: linux, bash, memory-leaks, xdotool

I'm trying to figure out why this simple bash script has an ever increasing memory footprint when running

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    pid=$(xdotool search --name "TeamViewer")
    if [ ! -z "$pid" ]; then
        xdotool windowminimize $pid
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

When I run `watch cat /proc/meminfo` and run the script, I see the `memFree` and `memAvailable` values drop at a steady rate. And it'll continue to happen until the system runs out of memory and has to fall back to swap, which is causing issues on my system

The original version of the script (below) was using memory at an even higher rate because of `--sync`, I think

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    xdotool search --name --sync "TeamViewer" windowminimize
    sleep 5
done
```

Any help would be appreciated

I'm using a 2011 Macbook Pro running Linux Mint 18.1 with 8GB of RAM

Comment: Are you sure the memory is eaten up by your bash-script and not by TeamViewer itself? You can use `top -p123 -p789` where `123` und `789` are the PIDs of your script and team viewer.

Comment: Yup, I'm testing this script in a vacuum. No other processes are running.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what happened but the issue has resolved itself somehow. Running this script no longer eats up memory.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    pid=$(xdotool search --name "TeamViewer")
    if [ ! -z "$pid" ]; then
        xdotool windowminimize $pid
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

This one still does though.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    xdotool search --name --sync "TeamViewer" windowminimize
    sleep 5
done
```

It's possible my testing methodology was flawed that caused me to believe that they both ate up memory.